# Cannot Reach Secondary Subnet on Same Interface

Tags: cisco, routing, subnet

I am running a Cisco 1841 which has an unmanaged Dell 2848 connected to it. Connected to a WIC card in the 1841 is a fiber run which goes to a subnet of devices. The primary subnet is 192.168.2.0/24, and the devices connected to the fiber run is 10.10.0.0/16.

When I connect a laptop to the switch and I hard-code a static address inside 10.10.0.0/16, I can ping devices on 10.10.0.0/16, can telnet into them, can get to their web UIs, etc. From any device on 192.168.2.0/24, I cannot.

10.10.0.0/16 is configured as a secondary subnet on the same interface as 192.168.2.0/24. See below:

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
description INSIDE
ip address 10.10.4.254 255.255.0.0 secondary
ip address 192.168.2.254 255.255.255.0
```

Shouldn't these subnets be able to see one another?

Comment: They should, do you have correct subnet mask and default gateway defined for each set of equipment? And I'm just going to say that the /16 configuration is scary.

Comment: I won't disagree, but that's not something I can control, unfortunately. As to your question, the gateways are configured as 10.10.4.254/255.255.0.0 and 192.168.2.254/255.255.255.0 on each respective client.

Comment: Does the router have an active arp entry for the 10.x.x.x device with the correct mac-address?  Also you might want to disable ip redirects with the `no ip redirects` command, if that hasn't been done automatically.

Comment: Yes, it does, although I cannot verify the MAC address is correct.